# How do I find all stored procs and functions that changes data in a given table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

It is easy to find all stored procs that “depends” on a given table by using Juneau (CTP3) or SQL Dependency Tracker (from RedGate).

However we have 100s of stored procs that just select from the given table, and hence make it very time consuming to look at the results from Juneau.

I need to find the procs that **insert/update/delete** data from the table.

(A search with a complex regex, is not a solution that will work!)

Comment: Only way I can think of that doesn't involve executing them would be to write some code that generates an estimated plan for all of the ones you have identified and parses the XML execution plan. Of course you can cut down on the ones to look at by only including definitions that at least contain `insert/update/delete/merge`

Comment: Even that wouldn't work if the stored proc uses conditional logic, dynamic SQL or `#temp` tables though.

Comment: @Martin, I was hoping for a tool that parsed the SQL then built up a detailed model to process

Comment: Well SQL Server does of course do that for you and you could look in the plan for insert, update, or delete operators on the object of interest. Could also use `Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql` to parse the SQL yourself.

Comment: The issue with relying on the plans is that you have to have a plan in the cache for all objects. Some procedures might not be called often enough to be in the plan cache, especially on an underpowered server, and it would be tedious to figure out how to call every single stored procedure in the system (since many may have required parameters, not to mention undesired consequences) - and again if the system is underpowered it may not be possible.

Comment: @Aaron Hence suggestion to generate an estimated plan. The rest of your comment still applies however

Comment: @Martin how do you propose to generate an estimated plan for every procedure in the system? Using Management Studio and going one by one? Again, like I said, extremely tedious.

Comment: @Aaron `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` could be used. Doesn't have to be done manually. Though obviously would have to generate it with some specific parameter values. Such as `NULL` for all parameters.

Comment: @Martin but how do you figure out that procedure x has 4 parameters (1 output), procedure y has 12 parameters (2 output), they're in this order, etc.? I'm still not getting how you generate all the fake calls automatically.

Comment: @Aaron - This is derivable from `sys.parameters`. Of course the approach has lots of limitations as already discussed but it could be used as part of a multi pronged approach that does textual analysis to get possibles and is able to confirm some of these as "definites" with execution plan analysis.

Comment: @Martin between setting that all up and then still having to parse the resulting XML, I think I'd rather just search and inspect the text, since we can get a pretty narrow and reliable list of possibles first with straight T-SQL. But that's just me. :-)

Comment: Yes I definitely would not do this for a one off task!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just did a string search over the folders that store the master copy of the stored procs.   It took a few hours to look at all the hits, but that was quicker than trying to write my own tool.

(I don’t understand why the tooling for SQL is so limited compared to C# for this sort of thing)

Answer (score 5):

With the same caveats as Christian, that there isn't really a way to be 100% certain that a stored procedure updates *your* table and not another, this method has a couple of improvements:

1. it uses sys.sql_modules, so no chance of missing a hit due to a boundary, or not capturing all of the text, for procs > 4k
2. it doesn't parse the object text for the table name, which can lead to a lot of false positives (table name in comments only, table name is part of a larger name)
3. it generates an sp_helptext command for each potential match, so you can copy & paste the output into the top pane, run it, and quickly scan to figure out if there are any false positives.

Code:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_helptext ''' 
        + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(p.[schema_id])) 
        + '.' + QUOTENAME(p.name) + ''';'
    FROM sys.procedures AS p
    INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
    ON p.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
    ON p.[object_id] = d.referencing_id
    WHERE d.referenced_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.your_table_name')
    AND 
    (
        LOWER(m.[definition]) LIKE '%update%'
        OR LOWER(m.[definition]) LIKE '%insert%'
        OR LOWER(m.[definition]) LIKE '%delete%'
    );
```

Now one weakness is that sys.sql_expression_dependencies isn't 100% dependable - but I'd still prefer to do it this way for the above reasons.

I wrote a pretty lengthy article about maintaining dependencies a while back:

- [Keeping sysdepends up to date in SQL Server 2008](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the system views for that.

[Here is an example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/12/10/sql-server-find-stored-procedure-related-to-table-in-database-search-in-all-stored-procedure/) how to find all SPs which are related to a certain table.
With a bit of modification, you can find only those that actually contain the keywords `delete`, `insert` and `update`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name, sc.text
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE (sc.TEXT LIKE '%your_table%' AND sc.TEXT LIKE '%delete%')
OR (sc.TEXT LIKE '%your_table%' AND sc.TEXT LIKE '%insert%')
OR (sc.TEXT LIKE '%your_table%' AND sc.TEXT LIKE '%update%')
```

This is not a perfect solution (for example, it will also find SPs which `SELECT` from your table **and** `DELETE` from another), but if you have hundreds of SPs which only `SELECT` from your table and do nothing else, at least these will be filtered out.

Comment: Most of the stored procs with only select from the given table, also updates other tables.

Comment: FYI `syscomments` is deprecated and included only for backward compatibility reasons. One of the reasons that other options are preferred (sys.sql_modules, object_definition()) is that syscomments breaks out a procedure into multiple rows if the body of the module is > 4K, so potentially you could miss some objects if the reference happened on a boundary (you also have to piece together the missing sc.text values yourself on a valid hit).

Comment: @Ian there are going to be some trade-offs here. It is going to be nearly impossible to find stored procedures that update the table you want and don't not other tables without actually reading the text. The best you're going to be able to do is to filter the list down considerably, but I will be shocked if there is a perfect solution that gets all of the procedures that do so and none of the ones that don't.

Answer (score 0):

**

> Try this SP_Helptrigger 'table name' sp_helptext'triggername' see the
>   code and then view the manipulation part in the trigger

**

Comment: Does this not need a way to call all the stored procs in the app?   (It would be greate if you did have 100 automated testing...)